# Can't install from using APT after trying to install code::blocks

Tags: apt, server, software-installation, repository, vnc

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
derek@derek-Satellite-C55-B:~$ sudo apt install tightvncserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libboost-system1.67.0 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libgamin0 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I downloaded code::blocks yesterday, which came with a series of deb files I assumed to be dependencies. I started installing each, but realized that I wasn't going to get it installed with the download I had. Next I added a repository for code::blocks, never got code::blocks installed.

Now when I run sudo apt-get update, I get this error:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                             
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                           
Hit:4 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease                                     
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                               
Hit:6 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease  
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease                       
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                  
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease   
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:12 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian unstable InRelease [2,521 B]
Reading package lists... Done      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And anything I try to install, I get an error:

```
derek@derek-Satellite-C55-B:~$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libboost-system1.67.0 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libgamin0 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't want to have to reinstall... I've got everything right where I like it!

Comment: What happens if you do what it says? `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? You probably also need to remove the launchpad ppa for codeblocks. You can do this in "Software & Updates" application.

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu has no focal, try using bionic instead.

Comment: This is the error I get when trying to run --fix-broken install:

Comment: Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks-contrib_20.03-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks-contrib (20.03-3) over (20.03) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-contrib_20.03-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/codeblocks/wxContribItems/libwxchartctrl.so.0.0.1', which is also in package codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 20.03
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-contrib_20.03-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)